# Spyder not updating variables over multiple runs

Tags: python, spyder

I just recently started python, but am not new to coding. I have been practicing a couple different things using the Spyder IDE. I am currently having trouble with a battleship program.

The first time I run it it works fine. But after I run it once, most of the time after I run it again, it does not update some of the variables based on the new values given in the code. What I mean is it is using the values from the previous run and does not update them until I end the program.

Usually it is the ship location and orientation word that does not update. I also just ran the part of the code that determines these variables and prints them and nothing else. That seems to work fine, but it seems the whole process is somehow messing things up when ran as a whole.

My code is below. A lot of it is comments to help understand my probably convoluted process. Any ideas?

```
"""
Created on Thu Jan 12 16:20:01 2017

@author: zroland
"""
# need random for ship location and orientation
import random as rng

# make the board a list of lists
board = [['O' for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]

# prints the board
def print_board(board):
    i = 0
    top = ''
    for k in range(len(board)):
        if k+1 < 10:
            top += '  ' + str(k+1) + '  '
        else:
            top += ' ' + str(k+1) + '  '
    print(top)
    for row in board:
        print(row, chr(97 + i))
        i += 1

# sets the length of the ship and calls the print_board function
ship_size = 2
print_board(board)

"""Sets ship orientation and determins the location of the ship based on that
(the ship cannot be placed at the end of the board if it is more than 1 unit
long)"""

ship_or = rng.randint(1, 2)
if(ship_or == 1):
    ship_or_w = 'Vertical'
    ship_r = chr(rng.randint(97, 97 + len(board) - ship_size))
    ship_c = rng.randint(1, len(board[0]))
else:
    ship_or_w = 'Horizontal'
    ship_r = chr(rng.randint(97, 97 + len(board) - 1))
    ship_c = rng.randint(1, len(board[0])-ship_size + 1)

# initializes the variable that keeps track of how many times you hit the ship
hit_count = 0

# shows location of ship, orientation, and size for development purposes
print(ship_r, ship_c, ship_or_w, ship_size)

"""Nested while loop. This is the game. The hit_count is checked to see if
the ship has been hit a number of times equal to its length. Need to edit this
to make sure you don't cheat and just hit the same spot multiple times to
win."""

while(hit_count != ship_size):

    """Initializes the guess location so the code will ask you for intput. This
    is to allow a the code to make sure you have a guess that is actually
    on the board. If it is not, it will continue to ask you for values until
    you do"""

    row1 = chr(97 + len(board))
    column = 1

    while((97 > ord(row1) or ord(row1) >= 97 + len(board))
            or (1 > column or column > len(board[0]))):
        """The first if statement is to make sure your column is good first.
        If it is not, there is no point in asking for a row. The column guess
        is initialized to be a correct value."""
        if(1 <= column <= len(board[0])):
            row1 = input("Enter your guess for the row: ")
            if(97 <= ord(row1) < 97 + len(board)):
                """if the row is a correct value, it creates/updates the
                variable we use to select the row in the board list."""

                row = ord(row1) - 97
            else:
                print('You did not enter a correct letter. Please try again')

        """Same as above. Checks for a correct row. No reason to ask for the
        column if the row is not right."""

        if(97 <= ord(row1) < 97 + len(board)):
            column = int(input("Enter your guess for the column: "))
            if(1 > column or column > len(board[0])):
                print("You did not enter a correct number. Please try again")

    # end of while loop that asks for/checks you guess

    """This is how the game checks if you hit or miss. The last conditional
    is the first one to think about. It determines the orientation of the
    ship, which in turn affects which guesses result in a hit.
    For the first if statement, if the orientation is 1 (vertical), it
    checks to see if your guess hit the first part of the ship (the actual
    location value determined at the start of the code) or any other
    space taken up by its length. If you did in fact hit the ship,
    it marks the board with an 'X' and tells you you hit it. It then
    increments the hit counter. The second if statement is for horizontal
    ships, and the third is in case you did not hit anything."""

    if((ord(ship_r) <= row <= ord(ship_r) + ship_size - 1) and column == ship_c
       and ship_or == 1):
        board[row][column-1] = 'X'
        print_board(board)
        print("You hit!")
        hit_count += 1
    elif(row1 == ship_r and (ship_c <= column <= ship_c + ship_size - 1)
         and ship_or == 2):
        board[row][column-1] = 'X'
        print_board(board)
        print("You hit!")
        hit_count += 1
    else:
        board[row][column-1] = '|'
        print_board(board)
        print('You missed :(')

# end of while loop that keeps asking you for guesses until you win

# prints hit count too to see if it is chekcking the value properly in the loop
print("You win!", hit_count)
```

Comment: I haven't made my way all the way through your code yet, but you should know that triple quoted strings are not block comments.  They are string literals, just like any other string, except when they are the first thing in a defintion.  Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings

Comment: What about the output you see makes you think that the values are sticking around after the program ends?  Are you running this multiple times in the context of a larger program, or are you running it directly each time?

Comment: I've run this a few times on spyder and it seems to work fine. It generated horizontal 3 times, but the locations were different each time. Can you elaborate more on what behaviour exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have had similar problems that I fixed by adding a few very short pauses to the code.  I can't find that code now but I think I used a few 100 ms pauses to allow the sypder to catch up.  (This may have been a different spyder version than what you have)

Comment: Patrick Haugh, I will take a look at the comment thing, thanks. And I look at the variable explorer and how the program functions. The variable explorer does not update until after the code is run even for the input values. Sometimes it would update in the middle of the code, but only after I input something else, if that makes sense. It isn't updating automatically in the explorer, and half the time, when it gives me coordinates for the ship and I guess that, it says missed. I believe this is because the values haven't been updated based on the explorer.

Comment: It is actually starting to look like the variables are properly being updated as it is running the more I play with it, but the variable explorer does not keep up properly. So it looks like they aren't being updated. Something else that made me think they weren't being updated is down in the section where the code checks for a hit, in the first conditional, the value of "row" is way to small to ever satisfy that, so it keeps thinking you miss. I should have "ord(row1)" instead of "row" there. By the way Patrick Haugh, I have been running the program directly, over and over.